# Merge serialized form with array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form and I am sending it with ajax to server.
Like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: form.attr('action'),
   type: 'POST',
   data: form.serialize(),
   dataType : 'json',
   success: function(data){
   }
});
```

And I receive in server something like

```
Array
(
    [forms_element_1] => 'some value 1',
    [forms_element_2] => 'some value 2',
    [forms_element_3] => 'some value 3'
)
```

Now i need to add to this form global variable that is array itself.

```
var statuses = [5,7,3];
```

I need to receive from POST in server side something like

```
Array
(
    [forms_element_1] => 'some value 1',
    [forms_element_2] => 'some value 2',
    [forms_element_3] => 'some value 3',
    [statuses] => Array
    (
         [0] => 5,
         [1] => 7,
         [2] => 3
    )
)
```

How can I achieve that in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn it into a param string with `$.param`, then append it to the serialized form (which is also a param string).

```
data: form.serialize() + "&" + $.param({statuses:[5, 7, 3]}),
```